# Can we get "Ticker feeds" in the chatroom?

Tags: discussion

I was chilling out for a while in U&L chatroom, and was for my surprise that questions asked in the main site were feed into the chat room:

> [image]

I was poking around about how could I get the same in the chatroom (yeah, I'm one of those guys that can't bring themself to leave +10 open tabs) so I could be alert of any interesting question that otherwise will miss my radars while I'm chatting.

Unfortunally, this is not a per-user preference but a per-room preference, so whatever changes will affect all of us. The characteristic is called "Ticker Feeds" (as you [can see in the U&L chat room info](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26/unix-and-linux?tab=feeds)) which differs of the "Message Feed" that we have set [up in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room?tab=feeds).

I believe chat owners can change this with couple strokes. The message is not intrusive. **And works for any ATOM/RSS feed**. So if you want your own feed, please just answer below.

[image]

[image]

**This is how it would looks like just with the Recent Questions**

[image]

Comment: A ticker feed of what?

Comment: @Oli I was thinking about "New Questions" but it can be of anything we can think about that has RSS/Atom

Comment: NOOO Ticker feeds are *incredibly* annoying. Seriously.

Comment: Oooh. That's why I was invited to a mysteriously empty room =D.

Comment: @Seth this is how it looked like after a full night http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf60L.png

Comment: I **HATE** ticker feeds. When the U&L room was [switched to a ticker feed](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/what-kind-of-feeds-should-the-chat-have), I left the room, not to return until I [found a way to hide the feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115224/can-i-silence-ticker-feeds-in-a-chat-room/170667#170667). (Cc @Seth)

Answer (score 8):

## No, I don't want to be cool at all!

Leave it like that...

Comment: We've had this before, we get too many questions on the site. If you want to follow new questions on the site sign up for the RSS with your own RSS reader.

Answer (score 5):

## No, it's a chat room — it shouldn't aim to duplicate an RSS reader and the /questions/ page

I'm widely against a wide proposition for adding all sorts of things to the chat room. It's a chat room, for chatting. We've had various proposals over the time it has existed including feeds and bots and each time I come to the same conclusion: they just add more noise.

This particular feature has existed for a long time and we use its non-ticker brother for low-traffic important posts (Meta and Ubuntu posts on U&L) but I just can't see the value in replicating the busiest feed on the site (/questions/) with a five minute delay or even just reposting stuff that gets a certain number of votes. People in the chat room are usually already on the site.

I'm in a rush and I'm not sure I'm making the second part of that argument particularly well... I can't see any benefit while I can see quite a cost; an annoying banner sliding down the screen on a timed interval.

Answer (score -1):

Well I like the Idea, But... maybe not the new questions.

How about the "Featured" questions https://askubuntu.com/feeds/featured

Answer (score -4):

## Yes, is a nice addition to the chat room... and is so COOL~!

What will being done:

- Activate the feed for [New questions](https://askubuntu.com/feeds).

Remember that you can feed almost anything here, from new, active, bounties, etc. **Any RSS/Atom!**